SQL Server: Remote Blob Storage
I am a standard end user in SQL Server, with minimum privileges. Is there a quick way to check if the Remote Blob Storage is enabled or should I go through the process of checking with database administrators?
I tried the following but it didn't work:
SELECT * 
FROM sys.extended_properties 
WHERE name = 'RBS Enabled'


I know little about it, but you might be able to detect it through something like SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES or maybe SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS, possibly with a WHERE clause if you know what to filter on. If you find a way that works, please post it as an Answer (below) on your own question.

As a standard end user you shouldn't know or care.

Does "minimum privileges" include creating a table?  If so, create a table capable of storing a blob and see if it you can store a BLOB, maybe some image or pdf and you'll have your answer.  You should only care that it stores, not how.
